# Settings in my .vimrc file are being superseded by other things - vim-gnome on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, vim

I installed vim-gnome on ubuntu. I notice that things I put in my $HOME/.vimrc file, like colorscheme and so on, are being overwritten by something else. If I start Vim, another colorscheme is used, but if I then do ":source ~/.vimrc", the settings that I want load properly.

Here's my .vimrc:

```
set t_Co=256
set paste
set number
syntax on
colorscheme zenburn
```

When I do :scriptnames, I see what seems to me to be a lot of things being run on startup (it takes a couple of seconds too...):

```
  1: /usr/share/vim/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim72/debian.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/syntax.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/synload.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/syncolor.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim72/filetype.vim
  7: /etc/vim/vimrc.local
  8: /home/tom/.vim/colors/zenburn.vim
  9: /home/tom/.vimrc
 10: /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/nosyntax.vim
 11: /home/tom/.vim/plugin/CSApprox.vim
 12: /home/tom/.vim/plugin/Light.vim
 13: /home/tom/.vim/plugin/codeburn.vim
 14: /home/tom/.vim/colors/Light.vim
 15: /home/tom/.vim/autoload/csapprox.vim
 16: /home/tom/.vim/plugin/coffee.vim
 17: /home/tom/.vim/plugin/color_sample_pack.vim
 18: /home/tom/.vim/plugin/ir_black.vim
 19: /home/tom/.vim/colors/coffee.vim
 20: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 21: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/gzip.vim
 22: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/matchparen.vim
 23: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 24: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 25: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/spellfile.vim
 26: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 27: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/tohtml.vim
 28: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 29: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
```

I guess some of these are overriding the things loaded from .vimrc. (CSApprox is one that I have in my .vim/plugins, but most of the others I haven't "chosen" to run at startup.

How can I change this so that what's in .vimrc overrules the other stuff? (Or, how can I stop so much stuff from being run at startup?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this part of the `scriptnames` output is relevant:

```
12: /home/tom/.vim/plugin/Light.vim
13: /home/tom/.vim/plugin/codeburn.vim
14: /home/tom/.vim/colors/Light.vim
15: /home/tom/.vim/autoload/csapprox.vim
16: /home/tom/.vim/plugin/coffee.vim
17: /home/tom/.vim/plugin/color_sample_pack.vim
18: /home/tom/.vim/plugin/ir_black.vim
19: /home/tom/.vim/colors/coffee.vim
```

It looks like you have some colorschemes in your plugin directory (Light.vim, codeburn.vim, ...).  Try moving these to a temporary location and see it it helps.

Comment: Yes, doing this solved the problem. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Tancata: colorscheme files belong in your /home/tom/.vim/colors directory.

Answer (score 0):

The only place in the standard VIM files where t_Co is set is /usr/share/vim/vim72/debian.vim and setting t_Co in my .vimrc works fine.

I notice you have a number of files listed there in your ~/.vim folder which run after your .vimrc - I would suspect that one of these has t_Co being set in it.

```
$ grep -r 'set t_Co' .vim/*
```

should tell you which file it is that's overriding your setting.

Comment: `t_Co` is not the colorscheme, it's the number of colors supported by the UI.

Comment: When Vim starts, it determines the value of the TERM environment variable, then sets the value of t_Co from the value of Co in the terminfo database.